# Simulating UVC webcam from v4l2loopback stream

Tags: kubuntu, usb-device, v4l, emulation

Is there any way to emulate a USB camera device (UVC) from my v4l2loopback stream at `/dev/video0`, so my linux can recognize it as a real USB device?

Comment: You can emulate USB devices including UVC with gadget drivers and a dummy hcd. There should be plenty of questions for this already on this site, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828356/linux-as-a-usb-uvc-device). Typically the gadget driver offers another "in" video interface, so you need some kind of explicit loopback.

Comment: I'm not a linux expert so I'm looking for some final solution. I checked this post you linked already. I couldn't even compile the uvc-gadget to start testing this solution. If this case won't have some final user solution I'll have to leave this need behind for now.